# Can Tridion 2013 update files without changing the filename?

Tags: 2013

Hi, all. Newbie, here!

I'm an end user for Tridion 2013 within my organisation.

Whenever I update a file (eg. PDF), I have to use a different file name or Tridion won't overwrite the previous version. As I'm sure you can appreciate, this can (and often does) result in broken links aplenty.

Our dev team tells us that this is a limitation of Tridion 2013 and that it may have been fixed in an update, but it is loathed to install any updates as it doesn't want to mess with the status quo of the platform.

Can anyone please tell me if an update would fix this?

Here's our Tridion build info:

Content Manager - Build 7.1.0
Content Manager Explorer - Build 7.1.0.66
Experience Manager - Build 7.1.0.79
Update Version - SP1

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you **edit** your question and add some further details to the issue that is happening, since it doesn't ring a bell to me which might mean it is not clear enough? It sounds to me like you are describing a caching issue, but you make it sound like the deployment of the change isn't happening. I'm hoping that some more information would clarify what it is so we can come up with the right solution.

Comment: BTW - since nobody seems to have stated this - Tridion itself has absolutely no problem doing this. It looks like a limitation in the implementation (custom cache solution maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few situational things that could affect this, but in general the process should work as below

1. Create first version of PDF e.g. `this-is-pdf.pdf`
2. Publish the PDF
3. Later decide to update the PDF by opening the existing multimedia Component and replacing the existing PDF with a new version. This can be the same name or different.
4. Publish the PDF, and all links (assuming dynamic linking is used) will update if name changes or remain the same if PDF updated with the same name

*you will see problems trying to create new multimedia items containing files of the same name, but this is often solved with a unique naming TBB.

To solve the problem without all the details is tricky, but I'd suggest looking at what fails when?

For example, a permissions problem on the filesystem could manifest as an error in the stop the publish happening during the deployment phase.